# UILabel misplaced after pushing to controller and setting hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Tags: ios, swift

Having a bit of an issue with my tab bar app. I want to hide the bottom bar in the next controller I push to. I have set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to true in the IB. I have a UILabel pinned to the bottom of the screen in this controller. When I push to it the label is not at the bottom of the screen but above it at the same height the toolbar was. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong here? Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest of solutions, but you could rearrange the label when the BottomBar gets hidden

Like this:

```
label.frame = CGRect(x: label.frame.origin.x, y: label.frame.origin.y + 'tabbarHeight', width: label.frame.width, height: label.frame.height)
```

You would just have to add the height of your tabBar to the y value

Edit: This is also reversible, so when you are navigating back, just subtract the tabBarHeight from the y value